# CodeMirror - "Uncaught TypeError: editor.getValue() is not a function"

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I'm relatively new with both CodeMirror and JavaScript so am trying to use them both to get to know them better.

I previously had code that when I edited/executed, it worked and showed the proper output. Whereas the bottom doesn't do anything when I execute, and when I inspect in Chrome, it shows the error that is mentioned in the title.

To try and explain it better here's some code:

**This works**

index.html

```
<textarea id="editor" name="editor" style="display: none;">
Some code
</textarea>

...

var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('editor'), {
  lineNumbers: true,
  mode: 'text/html',
  autoCloseTags: true
});
executeCode();
```

The executeCode() function

```
function executeCode(){
        var text = editor.getValue();
        var ifr = document.createElement("iframe");
        ifr.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
        ifr.setAttribute("id", "iframeOutput");  
        document.getElementById("iframewrapper").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("iframewrapper").appendChild(ifr);
        var ifrw = (ifr.contentWindow) ? ifr.contentWindow : (ifr.contentDocument.document) ? ifr.contentDocument.document : ifr.contentDocument;
        ifrw.document.open();
        ifrw.document.write(text);
        ifrw.document.close();
    };
```

**This doesn't**

index.html (No code typed into the textarea - executeCode() is the same)

```
$(function(){
    $.get('example.html',  function(data){
        $('textarea#editor').val(data);
        // now init codemirror
        var a = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('editor'), {
            mode: 'text/html',
            tabMode: 'indent',
            lineNumbers: true,
            lineWrapping: true,
            autoCloseTags: true
        });
        executeCode();
    })
})
```

Like I say, I'm new with both JS and CodeMirror, so chances are it's something pretty simple that I'm missing but would appreciate it if you could point out where I've gone wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: pass the editor object to executeCode();

Comment: @karthick thank you, tried that with no luck and the same result unfortunately

Comment: @karthick apologies, I made the mistake of trying it while tired, it's sorted now, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue and I was trying random possibility.
So for me removing `getValue` was giving correct output.

```
<CodeMirror
        value={}
        options={{
          mode: "javascript",
        }}
        onChange={(editor,change)=>{
              setCode(editor);
             
        }}
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

So most likely the issue you're facing is that you are loading CodeMirror 1 libraries while trying to use CodeMirror 2 method for retrieving the content of the editor.

[CodeMirror 1](https://codemirror.net/1/) uses getCode() [method](https://codemirror.net/1/manual.html#methods) to retrieve the content of the editor

```
var code = editor.getCode(); //a string with your editor content.
```

[CodeMirror 2](https://codemirror.net/) uses the getValue() [method](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#api_content) instead,

```
var code = editor.getValue(); //a string with your editor content.
```